# Problems installing antivirus

Tags: antivirus

I have been having problems installing any anti virus program for many days now.  I get a number of error messages:  the most recent one is:  An error occurred while loading the archive, etc. End-of-central-directory signature not found, etc.  Cannot find zip file directory in one of /home/ This is a common error.  Other errors have included physical address extension errors, root errors, etc.  I have tried a number of suggestions from Ubuntu help with no success.  Please help.

Comment: Post the actual commands and errors. Also: please do not try to install windows software on linux.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I started to post the error message as stated but abbreviations like pae, zipfile, etc blocked my submission.

Comment: Please use http://pasebin.com to post it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.   I went to pasebin but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Oops. I hit enter before completing my thought.  I am a newbie.  My reply did allow for terms like pae to be submitted (not sure if it only prevented it on my initial post.  I will try to copy and paste the error messages.                Thank you.

Comment: Here is the main error cut short due to length limitations: Archive:  /home/james/Downloads/avast_free_antivirus_setup_online.exe
[/home/james/Downloads/avast_free_antivirus_setup_online.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/james/Downloads/avast_free_antivirus_setup_online.exe or
          /home/james/Downloads/avast_f

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie servive](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

From the error messages, you seem to be applying `unzip` to a file whose name suggests is a Microsoft Windows executable, on a Linux system. This makes no sense. Why do you want anti-virus on Linux? Do you know how viruses work?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was just following the links for Ubuntu antivirus programs. I am new to Linux and not knowledgeable about computers in general - I was not aware that some of these programs are windows executable. I do not know how viruses work. I have an old Dell 700m that I cannot load anything above XP on (no longer supported), and I wanted to get some use out of it. I have read that many believe an antivirus program is not needed on Ubuntu, but have also seen comments suggesting to install one and antivirus programs are available. I do appreciate your input. Thank you.